# Proving the existence of sine and cosine Fourier transforms

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

I am working through the following exercise:

> Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function on every $[a,b],$ and such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|\mathrm{d}x < \infty.$ Show that the Fourier sine and cosine transforms exist. That is, for every $\omega \geqslant 0,$ the following integrals converge:
> $$ F^s(\omega) := \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\sin(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t, \text{ and } F^c(\omega):= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\cos(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t.$$ Furthermore, show that $F^s$ and $F^c$ are bounded functions.

My idea for the proof is the following: Since $f$ is integrable on $[a,b],$ then $f(t)\sin(\omega t)$ is too and
\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{1}{\pi} \int_a^b f(t)\sin(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t \right| &\leqslant  \frac{1}{\pi}\int_a^b \left|f(t)\sin(\omega t)\right| \mathrm{d}t \leqslant \frac{1}{\pi}\int_a^b |f(t)|\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}since $-1 \leqslant \sin(\omega t) \leqslant 1$ for all $t$. Taking $b \to +\infty$ and $a \rightarrow - \infty$, we get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|\mathrm{d}t$ which converges by assumption. Then use comparison to conclude that $F^s$ converges. Similarly, $F^c$ converges. Is this the correct way to proceed? Also, the problem quantifies that $\omega \geqslant 0,$ but I'm not exactly sure where that would be necessary in the proof -- maybe it has something to do with sine being odd?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct. The assumption of $\omega\geq 0$ has nothing to do with the proof and rather comes from the fact that allowing $\omega<0$ does not yield any new information since $\sin\omega t = -\sin(-\omega t)$ and $\cos\omega t= \cos (-\omega t)$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much